# Scylladb: Scylla write latency increasing over the time for continuous batch write ingestion

Tags: scylla

I have a use case where I am continuously ingesting data in batches into Scylla using gocql driver, During the heavy write test I observed that scyllas write response latency increases over the time, Sometime it leads to restart of scylla node,Where in case of cassandra latency  is constant over the time. I just want to know the proper configs for this use case so that i can achieve constant latency throughout the time.

Configs used for scylla cluster

Details of writer process Basically it is a kafka consumer .
The flow of the consumer is

1- reads 500 messages from kafka

2- 500 workers(goroutine) start writing it into scylla(cassandra) in batches(single batch contain data related to single partition) each batch contains avg 3k records(max => 20k).(replication factor of keyspace is 1)

3- updates the state of batch in counter table scylla.

4- commit this 500 messages to kafka

5 - back to step 1

soo, basically in the test I  am using 3 consumers . scylla is not able to cope up with the inject rate of kafka while cassandra matches the inject rate.

Shared the grafana dashborad of load test , please let me know if anything else is required.

[![inject vs drain rate ][1]][1]

[![scylla memory dashboard][2]][2]

[![scyllaIOqueue][3]][3]

[![ScyllaIo][4]][4]

[![scyllaDiskDetails][5]][5]

[![latencies][6]][6]

[![load][7]][7]

```
smp 16
cpuset 0-15
memory 80G
iops 
cat /etc/scylla.d/io_properties.yaml 
[root@ip /]# cat /etc/scylla.d/io_properties.yaml 
disks:
  - mountpoint: /var/lib/scylla
    read_iops: 265
    read_bandwidth: 99796024
    write_iops: 1177
    write_bandwidth: 130168192


Is there any other config which I  missed by which I can achieve constant write latency.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0yQc.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0RhS.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA4WY.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QAob.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U5UM.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG2my.png
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOtuQ.png

saw this logs in scylla container

WARN  2020-02-05 11:07:54,409 [shard 12] seastar_memory - oversized allocation: 1081344 bytes. This is non-fatal, but could lead to latency and/or fragmentation issues. Please report: at   0x2cf31dd
  0x2a1d0c4
  0x2a21e8b
  0x103d7d2
  0x103e298
  0x10070c0
  0x100cd14
  0x10289b8
  0x1028057
  0x1028f59
  0x2a003ac
  0x2a50491
  0x2a5069f
  0x2aba615
  0x2acedac
  0x2a330ed
  /opt/scylladb/libreloc/libpthread.so.0+0x85a1
  /opt/scylladb/libreloc/libc.so.6+0xfb302
```

Answer (score 2):

You reported that "write response latency increases over the time", but didn't explain how you measured this, or how much it increases. Does latency increase from 1ms to 2ms, or from 1ms to 500ms? Does the **mean** latency increase, or the **tail** latency (e.g., 99th percentile) increase?

Some of the ideas raised by other responses will mostly explain increase in tail latency. But in batch workloads like you are describing, you usually do not care about tail latency, and care just about getting a reasonable (not even low) mean latency (in batch workloads the more important measure is the throughput). But, if you are seeing the mean latency continuously growing and becoming unreasonable, what is usually happening is that your client's **concurrency** is increasing or in other words, it is starting too many new writes without waiting for previous requests to have  finished (see [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law)). You didn't say how you were doing your "batch writes". Are you using a client with a fixed number of threads, or can your write concurrency grow uncontrollably?

When your client correctly has fixed concurrency, Scylla still has to be careful not to make the client believe previous work has completed while in fact there is still a lot of background work - I explained this issue and how Scylla solves it in [a blog bost a year ago](https://www.scylladb.com/2018/12/04/worry-free-ingestion-flow-control/).

Of course it's always possible that Scylla has a bug in this area, so if you suspect it please report your problem - with more details - on the Scylla mailing list or bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for response !! I have updated the question with more details about writer process and uploaded the grafana dashboard of scylla .

Answer (score 0):

There is too few data, the best is to discuss on the mailing list or slack. The best is to use the Grafana monitor and to observe if you hit a limit. Compaction run in parallel but the scylla scheduler gives it a lower priority.

Could it be that you run something else on the machine besides Scylla?

Comment: yes , there are other java services running on that machine. we are not using dedicated machine for scylla . will post more data on slack.

Comment: Better use taskset to limit each server to its own cpus and memory. Scylla is planned to consume the entire machine and not to have unwanted neighbors. Scylla expects to use the entire cpu and disk and get surprised if it cannot - we have lots of algorithms and schedulers to make sure compaction will not go beyond the disk capacity. 

Stop that Java service and see how performance becomes consistent.

Comment: If you insist to run the other service on the same machine, Scylla has a shared mode you can configure in the yaml file but it's not ideal.

Comment: sure , will try running scylla on dedicated machine

Comment: i have updated the question with more details about writer process and uploaded the grafana dashboard of scylla.